# How to resize cordova webview ios 10

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, webview

I have cordova project, just a simple one that opens my web url in the webview. It worked nicely on older version, but most new in iphone 7 simulator it draws the top os bar (clock etc.) under the web page!

How to make the top bar dissapear or limit the size of webview starting just under the top bar ?

I use cordova-plugin-inappbrowser to open the url into app (not in a external window) after network connection is detected.

screenshot:
https://snag.gy/i9FtLh.jpg

Comment: What plugins are you using in your app, and what versions?

Comment: `"cordova-plugin-device": "1.1.5-dev", 
"cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "1.6.2-dev", 
"cordova-plugin-network-information": "1.3.2-dev", 
"cordova-plugin-whitelist": "1.0.0", 
"org.apache.cordova.console": "0.2.13" `

It was difficult to get the inappbrowser to open in a current window and not in external. It's old project but updated the plugins, maybe some main config is still invalid / wrong parameters. JS to open the inappbrwsr:
`var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(linkTarget, '_self', 'location=no,toolbar=no,status=no,titlebar=no,toolbar=no,keyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction=no'); `

Answer (score 0):

The result was to use cordova plugin "cordova-plugin-statusbar" and in deviceready js function StatusBar.overlaysWebView(false);